# Mercurial set up ACL

Tags: mercurial, acl

I'm trying to set up ACL. I've got it mostly  working. However, I've got a couple of specific questions.

Basically, I'm trying to set up a group `@group` that will be allowed to access a bunch of branches of the form `xxxx-integration-xxxx`. What I want to do is:

```
[acl.allow.branches]
*integration* = @group
```

However, that doesn't seem to work.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Also, is there a better place to ask this? I asked some similar questions on stackoverflow, and got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

After enabling the extension, you can run `hg help acl` to read its help (it's unfortunately not included in the [wiki page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AclExtension)). There you'll find this section:

> ### Branch-based Access Control
>
> Use the `acl.deny.branches` and `acl.allow.branches` sections to
>   have branch-based access control. Keys in these sections can be
>   either:
>
> - a branch name, or
> - an asterisk, to match any branch;

So, you cannot use general glob-patterns here. It sounds like a nice feature request, though, so I suggest you [submit it](http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/) in the Mercurial bug tracker.